# What should I do if I can't fight my opponent?

Tags: league-of-legends

Scenario: You're paired up against an enemy who outclasses you and you're unable to do anything meaningful in lane. You can't harass, you can't farm, you can't get a kill and if you leave the turret alone it'll die. You can't sit under turret; you're being killed from full health under turret. What exactly should you do in this kind of situation? Especially if you don't have a jungler or anyone else who can help you?

Comment: I'd say call for a lane swap... But that means you have to be able to rely on your teammates. Which is extremely hard to do in LoL...

Comment: I was afraid of that... What should I do if none of my teammates are willing to trade lanes? Is there nothing that I can do as a player to support my team without having to change our current comp?

Comment: I think Bunny says it well. Do your best to support your team, and really just hope they return the favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you just have to let the turret go. In cases like these, the problem needs to be fixed before it gets to this point. If you got massively counter-picked, either you should have switched lanes with someone on your team, your jungler should have made a bigger effort to gank or harass more in your lane, or you should just do the best with what you've got.

In these cases, you end up relying more on your other lanes and hope they didn't also get counter picked. Do your best to help those lanes if they refuse to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry raven if I'm answering too much but I love I just love trying to answer these questions xD

You may have answered your own question but incase you didn't what you should do is try to get as much farm as possible and try to survive till someone eventually decides to come and help or the tower falls. you shouldn't risk saving it due to the fact he/she will kill you then take the tower meaning they gain more gold other than the tower, take what you can before the tower goes down unharmed so you don't lose any more than you already have.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of scenario I´ve been before.

My strategy (because team mates just told me "Deal with it" after asking for a swap******) is:

- Explain why a can´t content that champ.
- Hug tower.
- Get gold generator items.
- And the most important, do not feed.

******You must evaluate too, if the lane you are asking for a swap is being dominated by your parthner, will you be able to keep the same situation in case of swap?